# What mechanism can prevent a user to modify a Angular2 application code?

Tags: security, angular

I am writing an application using Angular2 and when it comes to protecting some admin sections of the application, I plan to follow the proposed approach in Angular2's website : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#guards

So I will end up with a class like this one :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      // Use my service to determine if user is logged in and has credentials
      return this.authService.canHaveAccess();
  }
}
```

Once transpiled into JS code and executed on my user's browser, what would prevent a user to redefine the `canActivate` method so that it bypasses the call to `canHaveAccess` and instead always returns `true` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing.

If you rely on the code in the users browser for your application to be secure you're doomed.

Security needs to be enforced on the server. In the browser guards are only for the users convenience to not show options and forms that are not relevant for the user but such measures are irrelevant in regard to security.